# Finding static IPs after reboot

Tags: ping, local-area-network, arp

I am having troubling pinging IP addresses on the local network after rebooting or clearing the ARP table. I am looking for guidance on fixing this.

I have a windows 10 PC which is has a 4 port Ethernet card. The ports are all set up with static IPV4 addresses: `10.0.0.1` ... `10.0.0.4` with a subnet mask `255.255.255.0`.

Ethernet cables connect these ports to up to 4 pieces of hardware which have static IPs in the range `10.0.0.10` ... `10.0.0.255`

After a reboot I get a `DestinationUnreachable` error when I ping some of the hardware unless I try a few times (between 0 and 3?). The number of `DestinationUnreachable` errors before success for each piece of hardware varies, but depends on which port the hardware is connected to.

After I have pinged a piece of hardware successfully once, always succeeds on subsequent attempts, and I can see it in the `arp -a` table.  If I execute `arp -d` then again i have to ping everal times before I don't get `DestinationUnreachable`

Is there a better way to configure this? I want all the ports and hardware to be on the same subnet so that it works no matter which piece of hardware is plugged into which port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you have four different subnets with the same ip range. Probably the network stack has to check all four subnets for the actual device. i would check if you can bridge all four ports together and assign only one ip to your machine.

-> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections mark all four connections, rigth-click -> "Bridge Connections" -> configure the new bridge device.